# How to access a MySQL database from a Lua script

Tags: mysql, lua

I am writing a Lua script using VS Code 1.73.1 on a Windows 11 PC. I would like to write some data from the script to a MySQL database that is located on another (Linux) PC that is on my local network.

I tried the following:

1. add 'mysql = require "luasql.mysql"' to my code. This results in an error because the luasql.mysql module is not found.
2. 'luarocks install luasql-mysql' with the luasql-mysql-2.6.0-1.rockspec file downloaded from Https://github.com/lunarmodules/luasql. This fails because the Lua 5.4 interpreter is not found, and apparently I also have to install Git.
3. Installed Git but now it cannot find mysql.h. According to Google I have to install a local version of MySql. I tried that but no mysql.h file

What can I do to get the luasql-mysql module working? (Preferrably without installing programs/utilities that I am probably never going to use again)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `mysql.h` for a client library is provided by either mysql-connector-c or mariadb-connector-c (develop version with headers). The runtime version of connector-c will be used at runtime to connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you, I found the mysql.h in the connector you mentioned. However, now luarocks complains about other (lua) headers that it can't find. I'm afraid this is going to be way too complicated: too many things to figure out without a clear view on the path to follow. I was hoping for something simple that can be downloaded somewhere or a 'how to' description on how to get a working solution. I am still hoping that there is someone out there who can give me directions on how to get lua and mysql to work.